# How to test a component that un-mounts immediately after mounting with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-testing-library

I’m trying to use React Testing Library ie not use shallow rendering but I’m not sure how (or if it’s possible) to do it for this situation.

I have a `Parent` component with 2 children. `initialMount` is supplied by Redux:

```
const Parent = ({ initialMount )} = () => {
    if (initialMount) {
        return <ChildOne />
    } else {
        return <ChildTwo />
    }
}
```

When the appliction loads `initialMount` is `true` so `ChildOne` is returned. This reads the url and based on the value dispatches some Redux actions. One of these actions sets `initialMount` to false, which causes `ChildOne` to unmount and `ChildTwo` is returned by `Parent` instead.

I need to test that the correct child is returned based on the value of `initialMount`

If I use Enyzme's shallow render for `Parent` without Redux and mock the `appInitMount` value then this is quite easy to test:

```
test("Shalow render appInitMount=true", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ChooseIndex appInitMount={true} />);
  console.log(wrapper.debug());
  // Will show ChildOne is returned
});

test("Shalow render appInitMount=false", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ChooseIndex appInitMount={false} />);
  console.log(wrapper.debug());
  // Will show ChildTwo is returned
});
```

However I'm using React Testing Library as I want to avoid shallow rendering. I therfore need to pass in my Redux store to the test:

```
test("Full render", () => {
  const wrapper = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Parent />
    </Provider>
  );
  wrapper.debug();
});
```

The debug shows that `ChildTwo` is returned. I think this is actually the correct behaviour, as `ChildOne` is first returned, it dispatches the actions, then is unmounted and `ChildTwo` is returned instead. But how can I test this?

Can you intercept the Redux action to stop `appInitMount` being changed?

Comment: Do you care that `ChildOne` is rendered? Meaning, if something happens and then `ChildTwo` gets rendered correctly isn't this a test that covers your use case?

Comment: initialMount isnt the only thing in the Redux store that changes. Other things change as well based on the url.

Comment: Yes, but the point of `react-testing-library` is to not test implementation details. What's in your stores or even the fact that there are stores is an implementation detail. All you should test for is what gets rendered and eventual side effects—e.g. calls to the server.
I don't know the details of your example but I would test that what got rendered is what I expect.